# Protocol in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

What is protocol? How can we define it in iOS?

Comment: What is the use of protocol? In IOS

Comment: [Here's a link that might help you to learn the basics](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html).

Comment: google you will find a lot of tutorials and blogs on same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A protocol is an agreed set of methods that are implemented by a class, when that class states it adheres to that protocol.
Those methods might be optional or required, this is set in the protocol definition.

Best course is to look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18) (requires sign in) and indeed read the whole of this guide as it a good starting point to understanding underlying design patterns in cocoa and objective-c.